# How to set the computed value on a property of an object in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Below is essentially psuedo code which gives context on where I might want to compute the value of a property on an object referenced in the data object

```
<template lang="html">
    <section class="content">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
                    <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import VueFormGenerator from 'vue-form-generator'
import Axios from 'axios'

export default {
    components: {
        "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            model: {
                id: null,
                title: "",
                description: "",
                reviewerId: null
            },
            schema: {
              fields: [...]
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
      // get post to edit
      Axios.get(`/posts/10`)
        .then(response => {
          this.model = response.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
    },
    computed: {
        // Assume reviewerId is based on some user action such as selecting from a dropdown list
        // The question is how to set the computed value for this.model.reviewerId
        model.reviewerId(){
            return 42; // this does not work
        } 
    }
}
```

What is the correct Vuejs way to set the computed value?

Comment: Shouldn't it firstly be `'model.reviewerId()'` ? I think `model.reviewerId()` should have thrown an error.

Comment: So basically you are setting the reviewId within data and want to set it again in within a computed property? This seems wrong, use computed properties to 'compute' something based on data, for example compute the full name based on the first and last name within data.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Your comment ended up being what I wanted to know. I was not interested in "what I should do" or "design patterns" etc. That was not the point of the question. As I stated in the question it was pseudo code (somewhat contrived just to illustrate a point). You answered the point. Feel free to post your answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a dropdown to select it, try `v-model`: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/1/

If you want to change data property by some event (i.e. click a button), then use a `method`. Call this method like this `@click="methodName"`

If you describe your task in detail, I can suggest a solution.

If you absolutely need to use a computed property for some reason, you should read this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Anyway, name of your computed property should be different, than a data property.